# Data sanitization escaping HTML apostrophes

Tags: plugins

I have a plugin that I am developing that takes user input from a form.  After the form is submitted, the input is then assembled to create an 'About Us' type paragraph of HTML.  This is then used to create a page with the HTML as the content.

I have been playing around with different ways to sanitize this data and the problem that I am running into is that sanitizing the fields replace apostrophes with \'.

I tried using the html entity ' instead, but it still escapes it with a slash.

I am new to plugin development, so I'm not too sure on all my available options when it comes to this sort of thing.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can sanitize the incoming data, but retain my apostrophes?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It should add a slash when storing the data. And then you use [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) when you want to display it.

```
$str = "Is your name O\'Reilly?";

echo stripslashes($str); // Outputs: Is your name O'Reilly?
```

If a slash is not added, all sorts of unexpected things can happen because the apostrophe can be handled as the opening or closing of a string.

Comment: So, the only way to have those slashes not be there is if I actually have access to the theme and can make sure it stripslashes before it echos the page content?  The html is getting put into the content for the page in the database and the slash is getting put in as part of the content, so when the page renders, it renders those as well. In addition to the sanitizing, I am using the insert() method of the wpdb object when I insert the information.  Is that my problem, is there a double escape going on or something? Thank you and forgive my noobishness.

Comment: You don't need theme access. Use the filter: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content